# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm running a `DbDataReader` on a query to remove items from a dropdownlist if they are already attached to a specific submission, and I keep getting an error telling me the reader is closed. Can't see why my reader is being seen as closed here. What am I missing?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string x = Request.QueryString["SubId"];
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string displayQuery = "SELECT CustName, CustAdd, CustCity, CustState, " +
        "CustZip FROM Customer WHERE SubId =" + x;
    string broQuery = "SELECT EntityType FROM Broker WHERE SubId =" + x;
    string ddlQuery = "SELECT ProductId FROM SubmissionProducts " +
        "WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
    using (SqlConnection displayConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        displayConn.Open();
        SqlCommand DlistCmd = new SqlCommand(ddlQuery, displayConn);

        using (SqlDataReader Ddldr = DlistCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (Ddldr.Read())
            {

                switch (Ddldr.GetInt32(0))
                {
                    case 1:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(4);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(5);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(6);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        DdlProductList.Items.RemoveAt(7);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Ddldr.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: this is just a guess, but do you mean to be executing a DDL command here?

Comment: I really don't like this use of `using`

Comment: @Adrian: That's what `using`....is for...

Comment: @Gabriel: A DDL command is something I'm unfamiliar with, but I'd bet it's a case-sensitive method. ddlCmd is just short for dropdownlist. In any case, I've changed it to DlistCmd to avoid confusion.  
@Adrian: it's a matter of personal preference for me at the moment. I'm still learning, but using blocks keep things clean and close the connections automatically. Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the issue at hand.

Comment: @Gabriel I think he's using DDL here to mean "DropdownList", an ASP.NET control on his page.

Comment: Maybe connection is closed? But then exception would be earlier - on command execute...

Comment: What line does it throw the error at?  Are you positive it's complaining about the Reader and not the connection or something?

Comment: @Abe: The error message reads "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.", and highlights the line "while (Ddldr.Read())" in red.

Comment: Can you show your entire code snippit?  Including everything that has to do with `displayConn`.

Comment: Same error can be spotted if You reuse sqlconnection to execute other sqlcommand.

Comment: Maybe you can post bigger part of your code?

Comment: @VikciaR: The sqlconnection displayConn is used in other commands on the page, but the 'using' blocks close it each time, and as this is the first use, even if there were a connection conflict, I don't believe that would cause this error.

Comment: The close is in the code -- we don't need to see more code.

Comment: So, if you provided all the code from beginning - you would get right answer just in minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call `Ddldr.Close();`, especially inside the `while`. This way you are doing a first iteration, closing the reader and the second iteration will of course booom as the reader is closed. The `using` statement will take care of it. Simply remove this line from your code.

So:

```
using (SqlDataReader Ddldr = DlistCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (Ddldr.Read())
    {
        switch (Ddldr.GetInt32(0))
        {
            ... your cases here
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also the following lines:

```
string x = Request.QueryString["SubId"];
string displayQuery = "SELECT CustName, CustAdd, CustCity, CustState, CustZip FROM Customer WHERE SubId =" + x;
string broQuery = "SELECT EntityType FROM Broker WHERE SubId =" + x;
string ddlQuery = "SELECT ProductId FROM SubmissionProducts WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
```

stink like a pile of s..t. You should be using parametrized queries and absolutely never write any code like this or your application will be vulnerable to SQL injection. Everytime you use a string concatenation when writing a SQL query an alarm should ring telling you that you are doing it wrong.

So here comes the correct way of doing this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x = Request.QueryString["SubId"];
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProductId FROM SubmissionProducts WHERE SubmissionId = @SubmissionId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmissionId", x)

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (Ddldr.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductId")))
                {
                    ... your cases here
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Darin. I needed to understand the way the iterations were performed to recognize that the dr.close statement had to go. It's my first go-round with coding, and my trainer specifically forbade me from parameterizing in the interest of simplicity (the site is not for actual deployment), but yes, I agree, unparameterized queries are begging for injection.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
Ddldr.Close();
```

Comment: Haha, gotta love it when two hours of my life are reduced to 14 characters of errant code. Thanks Hogan.

Comment: @Brazos -- Yeah, it is a pain.  But every time it happens to me I cheer myself with the thought "I won't do that again."