# Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, datareader

I'm running an if else statement off of a datareader to query table data and activate/de-activate some controls on a page. I implemented a using statement to automatically close the connection and the reader when I close the block, but I still get the reader is closed error on each of my if else statements. What's missing? Code below:

```
string comnt = "SELECT StatusId FROM Submission WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;


    using (SqlConnection editConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        editConn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand statCmd = new SqlCommand(comnt, editConn))
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = statCmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.GetInt32(0) > 0)
            {
                PanelComment.Visible = true;
                PanelQuote.Visible = false;
                LnbFid.Visible = false;
                LnbCrim.Visible = false;
                LnbEo.Visible = false;
                LnbEpl.Visible = false;
                LnbNot.Visible = false;
                LnbPriv.Visible = false;
                LnbPub.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                PanelComment.Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: are you sure that reader returns rows? It has "HasRows" property to check before reading

Comment: what does 'x' represent? Is it a string representing a string? a number? You should get used to using parameters, concatenating strings to build SQL queries is dangerous, specially if 'x' is user dependant.

Comment: The field being queried won't accept nulls, so it's definitely returning rows @vityanya, and @InBetween, 'x' is a string used to store the jqueried submission id on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021207/invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not getting any results back. Get used to the following construct if you are not sure if your query will return any data:

```
while (dr.Read()) //will return true while there is data to be read.
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @InBetween. I'm unsure why the query wouldn't be getting results back, as the field is non-null and a check on the db table reveals the data is there.

Comment: @brazos: if the submission id is not numeric you might be missing '' in your query string. If it is numeric check for any localization issues.

Comment: Empty or not, this construct doesn't prevent the error.  I've ran into it even when I was just doing a `SELECT * FROM Authors` kind of query, while in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         if (dr.GetInt32(0) > 0)
         {
             ...
         }
     }
}
```

For more info, check this page:

[Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: `HasRows` was sufficient to clear my error - didn't need the 2nd `if`.  And for me, even though I was expecting a GUID, when I did `dr.GetGuid(0) > 0`, it threw an error because it was saved in the DB as a char(35) column instead of a uniqueidentifier column -- that would never pass the `if` test in that instance.  So let the buyer beware on that one, though I admit I had a special case...

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem due to mismatch of reader name. i.e.

```
SqlCommand sqlmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqldr.Read())
{

    idd = (int)rdr["Id"];
}
```

later I replaced the code

```
 idd = (int)sqldr["Id"];
```

and the error was solved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the select statement returns no row
and when you call dr.Read() for first time
datareader will be closed imidiately
for using data reader we always shows use if or while
like what leniel said

```
   using (SqlCommand statCmd = new SqlCommand(comnt, editConn))
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = statCmd.ExecuteReader();
       if( dr.Read())
        if (dr.GetInt32(0) > 0)
        {
            PanelComment.Visible = true;
            PanelQuote.Visible = false;
            LnbFid.Visible = false;
            LnbCrim.Visible = false;
            LnbEo.Visible = false;
            LnbEpl.Visible = false;
            LnbNot.Visible = false;
            LnbPriv.Visible = false;
            LnbPub.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            PanelComment.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand qr1 = new SqlCommand("select TransID, FType, FldName, LTrans, 
        OnCCBeforeLoad, LTop, LLeft, LWidth, LHeight, LFColor 
        from jwOndropExecButtonS where active = 'T' and MyType = ''  
        and LTrans = '" + TmpRajTransID + "' order by dbo.val(TransID) ", conn);
    SqlDataReader d1 = qr1.ExecuteReader();
    while (d1.Read())
    {
        if (d1.HasRows)
        {
            string MrFldName = d1["FldName"].ToString().Trim();

            if (d1["OnCCBeforeLoad"].ToString().Trim() == "Clr")
                ClearValueandToolTipforFieldName(MrFldName);
            if (d1["LTop"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                DisplaySetTopValue(MrFldName, d1["LTop"].ToString().Trim());
            if (d1["LLeft"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                DisplaySetLeftValue(MrFldName, d1["LLeft"].ToString().Trim());
            if (d1["LWidth"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                DisplaySetWidthValue(MrFldName, d1["LWidth"].ToString().Trim());
            if (d1["LHeight"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                DisplaySetHeightValue(MrFldName, d1["LHeight"].ToString().Trim());
            if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "Visible")
                ShowTextBoxWithFldName(MrFldName);
            if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "InVisible")
                HideandClearTextBoxWithFldName(MrFldName);
            if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "InNVisible")
                HideOnlyTextBoxWithFldName(MrFldName);
            if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "Enable")
                SetEnableforFieldName(MrFldName);
            if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "Disable")
                SetDisableforFieldName(MrFldName);
        }
    }
    d1.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
```

I got the same error once in a while at

```
if (d1["FType"].ToString().Trim() == "Visible")
```

saying `metadata not found`. Later I found that the reader was not closed, but the ASP.NET program using too much memory closed the reader automatically. It mainly depends on the SQL server stage. If it is a regular error then please check your connection.