# Invali attempt to call metadata when reader is closed c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the edited code I removed try catch to see where i am getting the exceptions. I alse marked where I edited the code. This code is getting on my nerves I have been googling this problem and tried everything i found. I checked every connection other then this code there seems to be no problem with them. each and every connection is closed.

```
    queryString = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE prd_code = @c OR prd_name=@pn ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Convert.ToInt32(txtpCode.Text));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", txtpName.Text.ToString());
    con.Open();
    //edited here
    using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
    // and here
    if (dr != null && fr.HasRows && dr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtpCode.Text == "")
        {
            txtpCode.Text = dr["prd_code"].ToString();
        }
        else if (txtpName.Text == "")
        {
            txtpName.Text = dr["prd_name"].ToString();
        }            
        txtpCompany.Text = dr["prd_company"].ToString();
        txtUnitPrice.Text = dr["prd_price"].ToString();
        txtDiscount.Text = dr["prd_dis"].ToString();
        txtFinalRate.Text = dr["prd_final"].ToString();
        } 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such record exists");

            if (txtpName.Text == "")
            {
                txtpCode.Text = "";
            }
            else if (txtpCode.Text == "")
            {
                 txtpName.Text = "";
            }
            con.Close();
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: which line you get this exception?

Comment: Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @Damith I get exception on this line
txtFinalRate.Text = dr["prd_final"].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

```
  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
           if (reader.HasRows)
              {
                 if(reader.Read())
                 {

                   if (txtpCode.Text == "")
                   {
                       txtpCode.Text = dr["prd_code"].ToString();
                   }
                   else if (txtpName.Text == "")
                   {
                       txtpName.Text = dr["prd_name"].ToString();
                   }
                   txtpCompany.Text = dr["prd_company"].ToString();
                   txtUnitPrice.Text = dr["prd_price"].ToString();
                   txtDiscount.Text = dr["prd_dis"].ToString();
                   txtFinalRate.Text = dr["prd_final"].ToString();
                }
            }
      }
```

Have a look at [What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: +1 for showing `using`. The only thing is that he does a one-time read, not read in a loop, so the `if (reader.HasRows) { while (reader.Read())` should be replaced by `if (reader.Read())`.

Comment: Actually you can remove the `reader.HasRows` entirely now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your finally block with:

```
finally
{
    dr.close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Also, you should look t other SO and other forum threads where similar issues have been discussed already.

[invalid-attempt-to-call-metadata-when-reader-is-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179139/invalid-attempt-to-call-metadata-when-reader-is-closed)

[InvalidplusattemptplustopluscallplusMetaDatapluswh](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/520074/InvalidplusattemptplustopluscallplusMetaDatapluswh)

**EDIT:**

It is always good to release resources in a finally block. I would recommend to to make `dr` *declaration* outside try catch and release it in finally block.

It is also possible that you query is not returning any record so use short-circuit technique to avoid this error:

```
if (dr != null && dr.HasRows && dr.Read() == true)
{
    // TODO : do your stuff here
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Look at the connection and reader close lines:

```
queryString = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE prd_code = @c OR prd_name=@pn ";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Convert.ToInt32(txtpCode.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", txtpName.Text.ToString());
con.Open();

using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr != null && dr.HasRows && dr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtpCode.Text == "")
        {
            txtpCode.Text = dr["prd_code"].ToString();
        }
        else if (txtpName.Text == "")
        {
           txtpName.Text = dr["prd_name"].ToString();
        }

        txtpCompany.Text = dr["prd_company"].ToString();
        UnitPrice.Text = dr["prd_price"].ToString();
        txtDiscount.Text = dr["prd_dis"].ToString();
        txtFinalRate.Text = dr["prd_final"].ToString();
    } 
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No such record exists");

        if (txtpName.Text == "")
        {
            txtpCode.Text = "";
        }
        else if (txtpCode.Text == "")
        {
             txtpName.Text = "";
        }
     }  

    dr.Close();   // <-------------------- Look here
    con.Close;    // <-------------------- and here
}
```

Comment: I cannot access dr in the finally block.

Comment: Thankyou your edit works but for only 2 to 3 times i search then there  is the same exception and after that i just keep searching and nothing happens no exception nothing.

Comment: I played around a bit and now the exception only occurs when data is found other then that it just shows the error message in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix issue by adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to connection issue. For more info refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars?redirectedfrom=MSDN