# i got "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" when using sqldatareader how to solve it in a three tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net

### when i click on linkbutton it gives error that is "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" my DAL method which returns dr is

```
private SqlDataReader getDownload(string sql)
{
SqlDataReader dr;
using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
cmd.Connection = con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
return dr;
}
```

### another DAL method is

```
public SqlDataReader getDownload(int auto_id)
{
string sql = "select mfile_name,file_data from Viva_Notice where auto_id=" + auto_id;
SqlDataReader dr = getDownload(sql) ;
return dr;
}
```

### my BLL method is

```
public SqlDataReader getDownload(int field)
{
GetPostAssign mGetPostAssign = new GetPostAssign();
SqlDataReader dr = mGetPostAssign.getDownload(field);
return dr;
}
```

### when i am calling it then getting "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
if (gvrow.RowIndex < 0)
return;
int field = Convert.ToInt32(lnkbtn.Attributes["RowIndex"]);
SqlDataReader dr = MclsAssignment.getDownload(field);
if (dr.Read())
{
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["mfile_name"] + "\"");
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["file_data"]);
Response.End();
}
}
catch (Exception)
{    
throw;
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly and *always* use the previous when you're posting a question - you should have been able to tell that it was basically unreadable long before you posted.

Comment: Once you close your connection, you also close the reader. You need to extract the data from the reader before closing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021207/invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed

Answer (score 7):

This is really a design issue - you can't really return a "live" data reader if you intend on destroying the connection, the `SqlDataReader` is dependant on it i.e.

```
SqlDataReader dr;
using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
} // the SqlConnection is disposed here
return dr; // dr is now invalid
```

On top of that, you are leaking your implementation detail through to your BLL/UI layers by returning `SqlDataReader`. You should *read* the data whilst the connection is active and return the actual data instead to keep things nice & clean e.g.

```
public class Download
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
...
private Download getDownload(string sql)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
        con.Open();
        Using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                return new Download
                {
                    Name = (string)dr["mfile_name"],
                    Data = (byte[])dr["file_data"]
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a design issue with you data access layer. It's not decoupling the application from the database as it's supposed to. it's just a different interface to the database than using SQL. You need to decouple them completely. That is you need to return data objects to the application. These data objects should then be populated in the DAL using the reader

So your method would be something like:

```
private MyFile getDownload(string sql)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        return new MyFile {
                  file_name = dr["mfile_name],
                  file_data = dr["file_data]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "It's a design issue with you data access layer. It's not decoupling the application from the database as it's supposed to. "

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement disposes the object in context (which is SqlConnection in this case) immediately after the last statement executes in the `using` block. This is the reason why you are getting the error "reader is closed ..." when you access it outside the DAL function.

Either you should remove the `using` block and handle connection open/close at the higher layer or better yet, you should convert `SqlDataReader` to an object or `DataTable` inside the DAL method and return that instead.
Example with DataTable:

```
private DataTable getDownload(string sql)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DataTable dt;
    using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: bt if i explicitely open it by using cmd.Connection.Open() then also gets error

Comment: Try out the data table solution I just wrote; it will help you. Btw, you'd need to change your caller method(s) as well to work on data table rather than data reader.

Answer (score 0):

you should change/add a method

```
public DataTable getDownload(string sql)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourconstring))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

then in your download click method

```
DataTable dt = MclsAssignment.getDownload(field);
        if (dt.Rows.Count> 0)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + (string)dt.Rows[0]["mfile_name"] + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["file_data"]);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Details: Error parsing near '����JFIF��'.

Comment: what is the line number?

Comment: it shows the alertbox and not showing line number.After executing all try code it directly goes to corresponding catch block

Comment: Dear after Response.End() it directly goes to catch block and shows error