# Open a Blob file from Mysql to PC using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to open a Blob(winword document) from MySql using SaveFileDialog using this code:

```
myConn.Open();
MySqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = view.ExecuteReader();
long CurrentIndex = 0;
long BytesReturned;


while (myReader.Read())
{
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string strFilename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        CurrentIndex = 0;
        long len = myReader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, 0);
        byte[] blob = new byte[len];
        BytesReturned = myReader.GetBytes(1, CurrentIndex, blob, 0, (int)len);

        while (BytesReturned == (int)len)
        {
            bw.Write(blob);
            bw.Flush();
            CurrentIndex += (int)len;
            BytesReturned = myReader.GetBytes(1, CurrentIndex, blob, 0, (int)len);


        }
        bw.Write(blob,0 , (int)len - 1);
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();

    }
    myReader.Close();
}
```

The exception I am getting is:

> Index out bounds of the array.

Any suggestions on different approach other than FileStream?

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: Sorry, Its an exception not an error. I dont know how to trace the line where the exception occur.

Comment: Just debug your code and you can see where you get it..

Comment: All i can see is this: A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll. Sorry just a newbie.

Comment: Read this: [Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: Found it. Thanks.  long len = myReader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, 0);

Comment: Are you sure your `myReader` has 2 column?

Comment: No. In fact it should read only 1 column. And 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No. In fact it should read only 1 column. And 1 row.

Based on your comment, I think problem is you try to get second column in this line (as a first parameter);

```
long len = myReader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, 0);
```

Because from [`SqlDataReader.GetBytes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public override long GetBytes(
    int i,
    ...
)
```

> Parameters    i Type: System.Int32 The **zero-based** column ordinal.

When you put 1 as a first parameter in your `GetBytes` method, you actually try to get your second column of your `DataReader`.

Changing `1` to `0` should fix your problem. Like;

```
long len = myReader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Fix it by getordinal but now it is throwing the exception:invalid attempt to read while reader is closed

Comment: @xitnesscomplex Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021207/invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed question. Also please use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to Dispose your connections.

Comment: I have used this as an example.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592455/converting-blob-back-to-original-file-type-and-making-it-available-for-download).